# cakephp - refer to "this" (i.e. controller class) in helper

Tags: cakephp

I want to have a helper build my forms for me, because it's repetitive. Usually, I'd use `$this->Form->input ...` to do it.  But in the helper, what do I refer to?

Comment: BTW, `$this` in the view refers to the view object, not the controller class.

Comment: Nearly 50,000 reputation?  How the hell did you achieve that?  You must be some kind of zen-master coder.

Comment: That, and I've been here a bit longer than you. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include helpers in helpers, which are accessible as an object property (i.e. via `$this->`), just as in the view:

```
class FooHelper extends AppHelper {

    public $helpers = array('Form');

    public function bar() {
        $this->Form->...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid repetitive typing using the [inputs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)() method.  Note the plural `inputs`.

Use 
$this->Form->inputs (...)